# DVD / CR drive not found after 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, mount, dvd, cd-drive

My DVD/CD drive (LightScribe Super Multi 8X DVD±R/RW with Double Layer Support) which worked on Windows, does not play or read anything once Ubuntu 14.04 was installed.

I see it in the BIOS, shows an LED and it spins up when a disc is inserted but cannot be read or played. There is no cdrom or dvdrom folder under `/dev/`. I see a `/cdrom` folder in the root but it is empty and `/mnt` folder is also empty. I am new to Linux so will need basic instructions for any suggestions anyone may have.

I have tried many things found in askubuntu but still not showing up in `/dev` or `/mnt`, won't autoplay any type of disc and VLC does not play or read them either. Some things I remember are; setting the region, manually mounting the device (not found), installed cdde (app),installed restricted codecs and reinstalled udisks.

VLC errors are:

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
```

`mount | grep ^'/dev'` returns the following:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

Here is the link to my laptop product specs:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01411391&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3689897

I don't know how to query the system for other information so let me know how to get anything else that is needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please include the output for : `less /var/log/dmesg|grep sr0` and `less /var/log/dmesg|grep cdrom`

Comment: Thanks for responding Ruslan. Both of these commands return nothing at all. It's like it doesn't even have any record of that drive anywhere.

Comment: Check the data cable, SATA? When CDROM is powered it spins disks, but since there is no any record of it makes me think it is not connected to the bus.

Comment: However if you can see it in BIOS tham means the data cable is connected. It is not a laptop, right? May be try to connect cable to another slot.

Comment: No, it is a laptop.

Comment: Did you try csmply reconnect it?

Comment: Thanks again @Ruslan Gerasimov Yes, removed and reinserted the drive but VLC still has the same error. Could it be a driver that needs to be installed or a config file that needs to be updated/corrected? Also, feel free to check my past work.  I have attempted to follow troubleshooting and installation instructions word for word but can't say for certain that they all were successful or without errors.

Comment: Is it a movie DVD you are trying to play?